# USB mouse keyboard and hub not working

Tags: usb, keyboard, hardware, mouse

When i connect my usb hub to my phone and try to use the mouse which is pluged in my usb hub it is not showing the arrow nor the keyboard is working.

Comment: Your device has to support USB OTG mode. Which phone do you use (manufacturer, model and Android version)? Also some keyboards or mice require more power than the phone USB port can provide. In this case try a different keyboard or mouse or a hub with own power supply. Do mouse or keyboard work without USB hub?